# how can I call jboss ejb's from apache servlet?

Tags: apache, jboss, ejb-3.0

I wanna call Ejb which is present in JBoss server from a servlet which is deployed in Apache server.Can I do that and If I can,How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that your EJB looks like this one:

```
package jboss.as;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class MyEjb {

    public long currentMillis() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

In your JSP you can now make a JNDI lookup and retrieve a reference to it:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="javax.naming.InitialContext" import="javax.naming.NamingException" import="jboss.as.MyEjb" %>
<html>
<body>
<%
try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
            MyEjb myEjb = (MyEjb)initialContext.lookup("java:module/MyEjb");
            out.println(myEjb.currentMillis());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            //TODO
        }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but how the client server(jsp file) which is apache in our case will communicate to remote server(ejb's) which is jboss??...Thanks..:-)